# Directory chooser

Tags: php, applet, directory

Hi all
does anyone know of an example of a Directory Chooser applet that will allow a user to select a directory on their local machine? I have a function written in PHP that extracts sub-directory names but I have only tested it on my own machine. I realise that there are security issues involved and was wondering if anyone has had experience with something like this. 
any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use `<input type="file"/>` to let users select files. Is that what you are looking for? Please clarify question.

Comment: @Gordon thanks for that, currently that is the solution I have in place. The problem is that a user cannot stop at a directory but has to keep drilling down through the directory structure until they get to a file. I need them to be able to select a root folder of their choosing.

Comment: in short `no`, you can't access users folders from the browser. you need to understand that php runs on the server on a request, php outputs html witch includes js/css/swf... witch are then rendered in the browser so php has nothing to do with the users hdd files/folders unless you tell the user to download and install the php inerpretor and tell him to run a php file on his local machine ( witch i don't think it's a viable solution )

Comment: What about using an applet then, I'm finding it difficult to find an example....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [JFileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY )](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setFileSelectionMode%28int%29).

The applet code will need to be digitally signed by you, and trusted by the end user when prompted, in order to show a file chooser (or to to many of the things you might want to do later with a directory).

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use [Moxiecodes Plupload scripts](http://www.plupload.com/index.php) to do what you need. It doesn't support entire folder uploads out of the box, but if your browser supports [BrowserPlus](http://browserplus.yahoo.com/) then you may be able to. See a recentish forum post on the topic:

> No, only browserplus enables you to select entire directories. You will have to shift select files in the other runtimes.

Source: http://www.plupload.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=236

I have never done this so I have no experience with it.

Comment: thanks for your help mate, I think browser plus is a great concept, but it would only work if all potential users have it installed on their browsers....All the others seem to only cater for file uploading rather than directory selection. back to the drawing board I guess. Thanks again for your time.